# Is there a way to scp copy a .tar.gz file from a remote server using ssh command?

Tags: ssh, command, tar, scp, gzip

I'm trying to copy a .tar.gz file from a remote server onto my machine. I have used the scp method successfully before on different file types but having issues using the same method with a .tar.gz file. What do I need to do differently?

The command I've tried is below..

```
scp userlogin@remoteserver:/ remote/file/path/.tar.gz local/file/path/to/copy/into
```

I get that there is 'no such file or directory' - i suspect this may be something to do with how the tar.gz file is compressed? Is it not picking it up?

Comment: Remove second white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source location in your scp command is malformed, try

```
scp userlogin@remoteserver:/remote/file/path/.tar.gz local/file/path/to/copy/into
```